# How to handle clock module with multiple screens in Kivy?

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I tried to move a ball around an origin (like the moon in its orbit around the earth). At first I created the ball object inside GameScreen. Then I got the AttributeError that my object does not have "move" attribute. So i created another widget called MainGame as a parent of the ball object. Now the error is gone but the ball does not actively moving. I could not figure out what i'm missing since I'm pretty new to Kivy. I guess it's about Clock module and my custom update function. All answers and helps are appreciated, thanks!

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.lang import Builder
import math
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock

class GameBall(Widget):
    org_x, org_y = 300, 300
    dist = 100

    ang_deg = 0
    pos_x = NumericProperty(org_x+dist)
    pos_y = NumericProperty(org_y)
    pos = ReferenceListProperty(pos_x, pos_y)

    def move(self):
        self.ang_deg += 5
        self.ang_rad = math.radians(self.ang_deg)
        self.pos_x, self.pos_y = self.org_x + self.dist*math.cos(self.ang_rad), self.org_y + self.dist*math.sin(self.ang_rad)

class MainGame(Widget):
    game_ball = GameBall()

    def update(self, dt):
        self.game_ball.move()


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass
class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass
class GameScreen(Screen):
    pass


GUI = Builder.load_file("gui.kv")

class MobileGameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        game = MainGame()
        Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1.0/60.0)

        return GUI

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MobileGameApp().run()
```

---- Kv file:

```
ScreenManagement:
    MenuScreen:
    GameScreen:


<MenuScreen>:
    name: "menu_screen"
    Button:
        size_hint: .2, .2
        pos: root.width/2 - self.width/2, root.height/2 - self.height/2
        text: "Play Game"
        on_release:
            root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
            root.manager.current = "game_screen"

<GameScreen>:
    game_ball: main_game.game_ball

    name: "game_screen"
    Button:
        size_hint: .2, .2
        pos_hint: {'top': 1}
        text: "Go to menu"
        on_release:
            root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
            root.manager.current = "menu_screen"

    MainGame:
        id: main_game
        GameBall:
            id: game_ball
            center: self.parent.center
            canvas:
                Ellipse:
                    size: 50, 50
                    pos: self.pos
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several problems with your code. One important thing I see in your code is creating new object instances when you actually want to reference existing instances:

```
game = MainGame()
```

and

```
game_ball = GameBall()
```

are creating new instances of `MainGame` and `GameBall`. Neither of those new instances are in your GUI, so any changes you make to those new instances will have no effect on your GUI.

So, you need to get references to the existing `MainGame` and `GameBall`. Those are the instances created by your `kv` file. One way to do that is to make the following changes to your code.

You can simplify `GameBall` as:

```
class GameBall(Widget):
    org_x, org_y = 300, 300
    dist = 100
    ang_deg = 0

    def move(self):
        self.ang_deg += 5
        self.ang_rad = math.radians(self.ang_deg)
        self.pos = (self.org_x + self.dist*math.cos(self.ang_rad), self.org_y + self.dist*math.sin(self.ang_rad))
```

And `MainGame` can become:

```
class MainGame(Widget):
    game_ball = ObjectProperty(None)

    def update(self, dt):
        self.game_ball.move()
```

And starting the animation now looks like:

```
class MobileGameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.start_updates)
        return GUI

    def start_updates(self, dt):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.root.get_screen('game_screen').ids.main_game.update, 1.0/60)
```

And then, to simplify accessing the `GameBall`, I added a `game_ball` to the `kv` as:

```
MainGame:
    game_ball: game_ball
    id: main_game
    GameBall:
        id: game_ball
        center: self.parent.center
        canvas:
            Ellipse:
                size: 50, 50
                pos: self.pos
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I now understand that the problem is - as you have clearly explained above- that i tried to create new instances instead of trying to reference to the existing ones. Thank you for your time and contribution. I really appricate that :)